# i getting issue login with facebook for php?

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

i getting issue login facebook for php 
error
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Answer (score 0):

Go Settings > Advanced 
Add Platform > Website

And in Site URL add your site url like http:/ /mysite.com or http:/ / 192.168.1.1

Comment: i go settings>basic > website after